# Sharing oauth tokens between requests on a Paw project

Tags: paw-app

I've got a Paw project for an API that uses OAuth 2. Everything works great, on a per request basis, but every request manages its own token. Is there a way to have a single OAuth 2 "manager" for each project, where each request can grab the latest token from that manager, rather than grabbing new tokens for each request?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are a nice way to handle this. We've described this in the docs:

> As you may often switch between development and production environments, or between several users, you may need to have several OAuth credentials you may apply to your Requests. You can keep those credentials in Environments, and then use them in the OAuth Header Dynamic Value.

Read more about [Environments](https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments) and [how to use Environments as Reusable Presets](https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments-reusable-presets) (this actually is the doc article that can help you the most for that).

Comment: Perfect! I think I'd seen that documentation before, but didn't realize that the value of that ENV Var was itself the built-in OAuth 2 agent. Thanks!